# Can you develop Windows 8 applications on Windows 7 PC and remote debug on a Windows 8 device?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-8

I am trying to work out the least disruptive way of beginning to experiment with Windows 8 development. I currently have a Windows 7 Ultimate PC (plenty of disk space, RAM and i7 CPU), and I have a copy of Windows 8 (not 8.1).

I have considered various options:

1. Convert my whole machine to Windows 8.  (Not ideal right now, as I am in the middle of other work, but I may have to do this eventually).
2. Dual boot Windows 7 & 8. (Can't get this to work.  Windows 7 is already installed, and though I can get Windows 8 to install on the second HD, I can't get its boot menu to see Windows 7. I suspect this would be easier if I installed Windows 8 first, but that would be a huge pain.)
3. Run either OS using a virtual machine. (I haven't looked into this yet, and I have no idea what is involved.)
4. As a final option, I wondered if it is possible to develop Windows 8 applications on a Windows 7 PC and remote debug on an attached Windows 8 device? (I'd prefer to do this, as it  is a way I have worked often in the past while doing console development.)

Does anyone have any experience of any of this - positive or negative? It takes ages to experiment with this stuff, with the constant threat of recking my existing work environment. I'd really appreciate any advice or pointers to articles that deal with any of this stuff.

Microsoft do their loyal developers no favours.  I've paid hundreds for modern hardware, Windows versions and Visual Studio, and still it seems difficult to say the least to develop for their latest OS.

Kind wishes ~ Patrick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 4 is not possible. In similar situation I went with option 2 and gratually migrate myself completly to windows 8.

If you have problems with boot try to ask on superuser.com or better search the web for guideline.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to develop applications for Windows 8 don't go with option 3.Please see [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70255/recommendations-on-running-visual-studio-inside-a-vmware-vdi-environment) post on installing Visual studio in VM.

Regarding option 2,verbatim from Microsoft

> You must install the older operating system first, and then install the more recent operating system. If you don't (for example, if you install Windows Vista on a computer already running Windows 7), you can render your system inoperable. This can happen because earlier versions of Windows don't recognize the startup files used in more recent versions of Windows and can overwrite them.

But as @Antonio said there may be roundabout for option 2.

Comment: Thank you both for those replies. They have saved me a lot of time, trying things that wouldn't have worked. Whole thing is still a huge pain. :-(